# IBM MobileFirst 7.0 - Xcode 10.1/iOS 12 issue on libstdc++.6.dylib

Tags: ios, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

We are using MFP 7.0 on our mobile app development. On Xcode 9, we don't have any issue and all our apps are running smoothly. 
When Xcode 10 and iOS 12 came out, we upgraded our MacBooks but we are having issues during compilation. We've added the library **libstdc++.6.dylib** as recommended from forums. It is working fine when we run on Simulator but if we try to test in real devices (iPhone/iPad), we are getting error message "**../native/Frameworks/libstdc++.6.dylib, missing required architecture arm64"**.

Here's the actual warning/error log in my xcode when i run the app targeting my iphone device:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jm/Documents/App/native/Frameworks/libstdc++.6.dylib, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/jm/Documents/App/native/Frameworks/libstdc++.6.dylib (2 slices)
>   Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>     "std::basic_ostringstream, std::allocator >::basic_ostringstream(std::_Ios_Openmode)", referenced from:
>         +[NSNumber(UCUtils) doubleToString:] in libWorklightStaticLibProject.a(NSNumber-UCUtils.o)
>     "std::ostream::operator<<(double)", referenced from:
>         +[NSNumber(UCUtils) doubleToString:] in libWorklightStaticLibProject.a(NSNumber-UCUtils.o)
>     "std::string::c_str() const", referenced from:
>         +[NSNumber(UCUtils) doubleToString:] in libWorklightStaticLibProject.a(NSNumber-UCUtils.o)
>     "std::basic_string, std::allocator >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
>         +[NSNumber(UCUtils) doubleToString:] in libWorklightStaticLibProject.a(NSNumber-UCUtils.o)
>     "std::basic_ostringstream, std::allocator >::str() const", referenced from:
>         +[NSNumber(UCUtils) doubleToString:] in libWorklightStaticLibProject.a(NSNumber-UCUtils.o)
>     "std::basic_ostringstream, std::allocator >::~basic_ostringstream()", referenced from:
>         +[NSNumber(UCUtils) doubleToString:] in libWorklightStaticLibProject.a(NSNumber-UCUtils.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> :-1: ignoring file /Users/jm/Documents/App/native/Frameworks/libstdc++.6.dylib, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/jm/Documents/App/native/Frameworks/libstdc++.6.dylib (2 slices)
>
> :-1: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>
> :-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 2):

I tried following on MFP v6.2 which worked fine on device. You can try the same. Can you give more details from your question from where you were copying the stdlibc++ libraries.

1. From your Xcode 9 machine

copy the file: (libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd) and (libstdc++.6.tbd) 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib
and
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib

2. Paste to following path on  Xcode 10 machine

copy the file: (libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd) and (libstdc++.6.tbd) to :
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib`
and
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/usr/lib`

(Please note the distinction "iPhoneOS" and "iPhoneSimulator")

3. Add the copied library (libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd) and (libstdc++.6.tbd)  to “Build Phase-> Link libraries” Path of Xcode project.
4. clean xcode and rebuild it.
5. Execute on iOS 12 device

Note :For Simulator issues with `/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator`, can try copy the original file: libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib and libstdc++.6.dylib and libstdc++.dylib to: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib`

But sometime even doing does not work, recommeneded to run on iOS 11 simulator

Comment: Thanks SSuman99. We've tried as you suggested, unfortunately, we are getting the same issue. I think the only solution now is to migrate to MFP 7.1.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2018/07/23/mfp-support-for-ios12/

Comment: I wonder why its not working for you as I tested myself on 6.2  there must be some missing pieces. However, its a better decision to move to v7.1 because iOS12  is still not a supported configuration on Worklight 7.0 apps as this is not fully tested  and there could be issues elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, no other option but to upgrade and to be fully compatible with iOS 12. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just an update to this issue. After we upgraded to MFP v7.1, the app has been successfully launched for all environments, iOS, Android and Browser. However,  a new issue arise again on iOS. Both Android and browser are working fine end to end but for iOS, when we reach the screen where we are calling an Adapter (web service), we get error 'Not Found - Targeted resource "PushEnvironment" does not exist. Pls. note that all environments are calling the same adapter. We don't have any idea what is this PushEnvironment thing. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "We've added the library libstdc++.6.dylib as recommended from forums." , It seems the library libstdc++.6.dylib you copied from previous Xcode version is not built for arm64 but just for simulator architecture.
The best way is to get rid of libstdc++ library by replacing it with libc++ in linked libraries in build phase for Xcode project.This works well with MobileFirst version v7.1 and v8.0.

Comment: Thanks SSuman99 on your response. Yes we did used libc++ already in linked library but the thing is, we are still using MFP 7.0.  We cannot upgrade at this point as we only 1 week left to comply as upgrading MobileFirst will need time to perform all the needed process and testing. Any other wprk around you can suggest aside from moving to v7.1/v8.0? Thanks in advance